# Get the value of a column from sql server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

I want a column value from database. Column datatype is decimal.
If the column value is less than 1, I will send an email to a recipient .

The code looks like this :

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
   {
         // I want to put the code in here

    }
    if (column less than 1)
    {
        try
        { 
           MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
           mailMessage.To.Add("me@myemail.com");
           mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("fromemail@email.com");
           mailMessage.Subject = "ASP.NET e-mail test";
           mailMessage.Body = "Hello world,\n\nThis is an ASP.NET test e-mail!";
           SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();

           smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);

           Response.Write("E-mail sent!");
           Label1.Text = "Sent Perfectly!";
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
      Response.Write("Could not send the e-mail - error: " + ex.Message);
      Label1.Text = "Could not send the e-mail - error: " + ex.Message;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes Sir .. I want a code ..

Comment: 2 upvotes? SO just wants code. I don't find any reason to upvote.

Comment: But I wanted to get the all the value in that column .. and do my if statement @ImadoddinIbnAlauddin

Comment: See my answer and reply back if you are facing any problem

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: I don't want to begin a discussion here but i agree with John. Everything you need is in the first google result for "how to make sql request".

Comment: OK ! I'm so sorry .. I just don't know where to start .. Okay ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because shows no effort, just asking for a code

Comment: Why would you ? All i wanted to ask is where to start .. Why so rude ? I'm not as good as you and my mind is not sharp as yours ... So cruel ..

Answer (score 1):

to get one decimal value from your Database

```
string ConnectionString = "data source=192.168.x.x;database=database;user id=user;password=pass";
string Command = "SELECT TOP 1 Column FROM Table";
using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    myConnection.Open();
    using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(Command, myConnection))
    {
        decimal Result = (decimal)myCommand.ExecuteScalar();
    }
}
```

Comment: how will i get the value of the `decimal result` and send an email if it is below 1 ? and I want to get all the data on that column ..

Comment: just follow your code `if (Result < 1)` ... you need to declare `decimal Result` outside the usings

Comment: what do u mean ? can u please help me ? i'm still a newbie in this language ..

Answer (score 1):

Putting actual code would not be the best solution here but you can follow these steps to resolve this.

1. Inside that `using` block, make use of objects of `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` classes to put in your connection string and the SP details respectively.
2. You can then use the `SqlCommand` object to fire your SP using `ExecuteReader` and store the results in a `SqlDataReader` object like this :

   `SqlDataReader dr1 = command.ExecuteReader();`
3. You can then read the result from the dataReader object like this :

   `int st = Convert.ToInt32(dr1["ReturnRes"]);`
4. This is `int` but you can use `decimal` and Convert it as needed. Then you just have to branch your code as per the result obtained in that variable.

Hope this clears up the idea of how to proceed with your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Get All values in `DataTable`

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
string Command = "SELECT ColumnName value FROM TableName";
using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("YourConnectionString"))
{
    using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(Command, myConnection))
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(myCommand);
        da.Fill(dt);
    }
}
```

find all values, check them and send mail

```
for(int i = 0; i<dt.Rows.Count -1; i++)
{
    if (dt.Rows[i]["ColumnName"] != null) 
    {
          if ((decimal)dt.Rows[i]["ColumnName"] < 1)
          {
               //Send Mail
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get an error `Additional information: Specified cast is not valid.` on this part `if ((decimal)dt.Rows[i]["ColumnName"] < 1)`

Comment: and additional .. : I have nulls in my column ,, I just wanted to ignore the null ..

Comment: Still got same error

Comment: does you column contains anything like string or non decimel?

Comment: i declared the column `C_Variance` as decimal(36,1) and other fields are null ..